# error in AUTH_USER_MODEL after upgrading Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.2

i am working on django 1.8 and python 2.7 then i upgraded my django to 2.2 and python to 3.6 but when i run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

i got error in terminal that show me:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.User' that has not been installed
```

i use `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'` in `setting.py`

no changes i made for the code but just i upgraded my django and python

Comment: Paste the User model code?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading djangorestframework might help

```
pip install -U djangorestframework
```